# Update or otherwise create an entry in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-update

I want to update or create a new entry in a table with normal SQL (not MySQL).
My table has columns: T_ID, ITERATION, COMMENT

I know that I can update my table with:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET ITERATION = ITERATION + 1
    WHERE T_ID = 1;
```

But if no entry with T_ID = 1 exists I want to create an entry with ITERATION = 1 and T_ID = 1 and as COMMENT nothing.

Is this possible by using a normal SQL statement?

Comment: It can be implemented in a stored procedure

Comment: You need a merge clause. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: But is this possible by using a normal SQL statement? I would prefer not using PL/SQL or similar things.

Comment: Merge is an SQL construct.

Comment: @Puddle No, there is no "standard" SQL syntax for an INSERT-or-UPDATE.  You have to use an IF/ELSE or a MERGE (which is basically an IF/ELSE wrapped into one statement.

Comment: @I_am_Batman There's no _standard_ SQL construct for an upsert, though - it's different depending on the SQL platform you are using.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That answers my question. I thought that it might be possible.

Comment: @DStanley, ok thanks for correcting, point noted. Let's say atleast for Oracle and SQL server, merge option exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible by using a normal SQL statement?

No - there is no "standard" SQL construct for an "upsert" (or [Merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL))) in one statement.  Different SQL systems have implemented mechanism to perform an "update if exists" operation, such as MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or Oracle and SQL Server's `MERGE` syntax, but nothing in "standard" SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do it in a stored procedure.  Something like this where you're checking to see if anything exists where T_ID = 1.  Then based off that conclusion you'll either update or insert.

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE T_ID = 1)
BEGIN
   UPDATE table SET ITERATION = ITERATION + 1 WHERE T_ID = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table (T_ID, ITERATION, COMMENT)
   VALUES (1, 1, '')
END
COMMIT TRAN
```